# RSS feed in excel

Tags: office-interop

How do I import an RSS feed into Microsoft Excel ? For e.g. I would like to show a daily quote in the Excel file, which is pulled from an external RSS feed URL.

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Here's a video explaining it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO2wFl2sUvI

Answer (score 0):

Cheeckout these links

1. http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/07/30/rss-feeds-excel/
2. http://www.s-anand.net/blog/rss-feeds-in-excel/
3. http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/extract-data-from-web-pages-into-excel/1979/